# Port 443 status randomly changes to 'filtered'. Restarting nginx fixes it for a while

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

Server OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5

The problem happens randomly without apparent reason.

Nginx stops receiving https requests.
Any https request to the server gets "Connection timeout" response.
All my ssl certificates are valid and not expired.
Running `systemctl restart nginx` helps but apparently does not fix the problem. After a few days it happens again.

What I've checked:

`systemctl status nginx`
*the service is active

there are no errors in nginx logs*

`nmap <server-ip>`

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp  open     http
443/tcp filtered https
```

`journalctl`
*no errors*

`dmesg`
*no errors*

`ufw status`
*inactive*

`iptables -S`

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

How can I find the cause of the problem? Any help is appreciated.

**UPD.**

in my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
...
worker_connections 1024;
```

I didn't know about ngx_http_stub_status_module, when the problem happened.
But for what it's worth right now when everything works the output looks like this:

```
Active connections: 37  
server accepts handled requests  
 107208 107208 629578  
Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 36
```

`systemctl status nginx`

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-23 11:09:41 MSK; 1 day 6h ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
 Main PID: 12699 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1107)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─  603 nginx: worker process
           └─12699 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
```

**UPDATE 11.07.21**

The problem happened again and I've run some additional commands:

`ss -plnt`

```
   State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port    
    LISTEN   16        128               127.0.0.1:7141             0.0.0.0:*       
    LISTEN   38        128                 0.0.0.0:80               0.0.0.0:*       
    LISTEN   0         128           127.0.0.53%lo:53               0.0.0.0:*       
    LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*       
    LISTEN   129       128                 0.0.0.0:443              0.0.0.0:*       
    LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:80                  [::]:*       
    LISTEN   0         100                   [::1]:8761                [::]:*       
    LISTEN   0         50                    [::1]:8762                [::]:*       
    LISTEN   75        128                    [::]:443                 [::]:*
```

---

`ss -atn sport == 443`

```
   State        Recv-Q    Send-Q    Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port                 
    LISTEN       129       128             0.0.0.0:443           0.0.0.0:*
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.14:50752                
    CLOSE-WAIT   62        0        <my-server-ip>:443    190.88.157.209:53692                
    CLOSE-WAIT   174       0        <my-server-ip>:443   188.120.116.128:9068                 
    CLOSE-WAIT   414       0        <my-server-ip>:443      51.89.155.27:20400                
    CLOSE-WAIT   370       0        <my-server-ip>:443     63.143.42.242:35772                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63490                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443     103.76.44.243:58496                
    CLOSE-WAIT   414       0        <my-server-ip>:443      51.89.155.27:21866                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443    140.238.83.181:44782                
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.14:64912                
    CLOSE-WAIT   304       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.18:11146                
    CLOSE-WAIT   279       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63404                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443   152.169.229.115:57877                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63481                
    CLOSE-WAIT   217       0        <my-server-ip>:443      93.158.90.56:27109                
    CLOSE-WAIT   218       0        <my-server-ip>:443      207.38.88.75:12518                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443    124.240.214.92:32336                
    CLOSE-WAIT   373       0        <my-server-ip>:443   128.199.195.156:38372                
    CLOSE-WAIT   304       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.26:23620                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443     103.76.44.243:58500                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443       174.2.25.50:48538                
    CLOSE-WAIT   377       0        <my-server-ip>:443     63.143.42.246:54248                
    CLOSE-WAIT   295       0        <my-server-ip>:443       54.156.8.33:20089                
    CLOSE-WAIT   217       0        <my-server-ip>:443      93.158.90.56:14355                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443    124.240.214.92:32337                
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.41:6010                 
    CLOSE-WAIT   217       0        <my-server-ip>:443      93.158.90.56:55117                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443       50.24.7.102:45514                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443      66.102.8.216:35146                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443       174.2.25.50:48552                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63510                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443     103.76.44.243:58498                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443   105.245.106.245:57395                
    CLOSE-WAIT   295       0        <my-server-ip>:443       54.156.8.33:2177                 
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63500                
    CLOSE-WAIT   373       0        <my-server-ip>:443     63.143.42.242:37358                
    CLOSE-WAIT   174       0        <my-server-ip>:443   188.120.116.128:9097                 
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443      66.102.8.216:58832                
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.41:18880                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63482                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443      66.249.70.51:38665                
    CLOSE-WAIT   149       0        <my-server-ip>:443    190.88.157.209:53691                
    CLOSE-WAIT   217       0        <my-server-ip>:443      93.158.90.56:29591                
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.41:40028                
    CLOSE-WAIT   1         0        <my-server-ip>:443      66.249.64.22:58748                
    CLOSE-WAIT   304       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.18:43156                
    CLOSE-WAIT   211       0        <my-server-ip>:443      207.38.88.75:12734                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443     151.82.77.142:14303                
    CLOSE-WAIT   1         0        <my-server-ip>:443     5.255.231.155:55850                
    CLOSE-WAIT   1         0        <my-server-ip>:443      66.249.64.24:51073                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63512                
    CLOSE-WAIT   373       0        <my-server-ip>:443     63.143.42.251:37356                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443       50.24.7.102:45516                
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.34:50266                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443   105.245.106.245:57397                
    ESTAB        406       0        <my-server-ip>:443       95.91.75.32:3099                 
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.14:26910                
    CLOSE-WAIT   217       0        <my-server-ip>:443      93.158.90.56:31917                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443      36.90.163.47:53848                
    CLOSE-WAIT   217       0        <my-server-ip>:443      93.158.90.56:16593                
    CLOSE-WAIT   414       0        <my-server-ip>:443      51.89.155.27:22292                
    CLOSE-WAIT   316       0        <my-server-ip>:443     5.255.231.155:47018                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443       174.2.25.50:48546                
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.14:2850                 
    CLOSE-WAIT   304       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.18:38278                
    CLOSE-WAIT   217       0        <my-server-ip>:443      93.158.90.56:49885                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63508                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443      66.249.70.49:50315                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63483                
    ESTAB        0         0        <my-server-ip>:443     78.10.205.246:47113                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63509                
    CLOSE-WAIT   1         0        <my-server-ip>:443     85.52.243.124:46299                
    CLOSE-WAIT   525       0        <my-server-ip>:443       68.4.27.246:63485                
    CLOSE-WAIT   518       0        <my-server-ip>:443      66.102.8.216:45559                
    CLOSE-WAIT   294       0        <my-server-ip>:443     3.238.138.173:57324                
    CLOSE-WAIT   307       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.41:4624                 
    CLOSE-WAIT   304       0        <my-server-ip>:443    185.191.171.26:60256                
    CLOSE-WAIT   373       0        <my-server-ip>:443     63.143.42.242:57958                
    ESTAB        184       0        <my-server-ip>:443       95.91.75.32:34140                
    CLOSE-WAIT   1         0        <my-server-ip>:443   186.179.166.137:51668                
...
```

---

`ss -p | grep nginx | grep -i estab | wc -l`

`0`

---

**Note:** Normally `ss -plnt` output looks like this:

```
State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:80               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128           127.0.0.53%lo:53               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:443              0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:7141             0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:80                  [::]:*
LISTEN   0         100                   [::1]:8761                [::]:*
LISTEN   0         50                    [::1]:8762                [::]:*
LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:443                 [::]:*
```

---

And `ss -atn sport == 443` output normally looks like this:

```
State       Recv-Q     Send-Q   Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port                 
LISTEN      0          128            0.0.0.0:443          0.0.0.0:*
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.79:49070                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     66.249.70.53:54557                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.41:30578                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.79:38618                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     66.249.64.22:38639                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443    17.121.113.26:64778                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.79:42886                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.67:47202                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.79:15380                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443   223.236.100.52:39478                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443    41.186.78.109:26127                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     3.235.40.235:33774                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     66.249.64.23:55669                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443   37.210.126.179:48524                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443      52.71.251.5:55276                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443   201.230.235.12:51712                
ESTAB       0          0       <my-server-ip>:443  197.158.235.224:44578                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.79:26606                
TIME-WAIT   0          0       <my-server-ip>:443     54.36.148.79:60100                
...
```

Comment: too many connections? when this happens what would tell `ss -atn sport == 443`? many connections? Is the `Recv-Q` > `Send-Q` (which is the listen backlog) value in the `LISTEN` entry?

Comment: Please provide Nginx logs and nginx status information

Comment: I'll run the command next time the problem happens. But if that was the case wouldn't there be errors in nginx logs? e.g. "worker_connections are not enough" or "Too many open files"?

Comment: @VincentH Like I said there are no errors in the logs. And access logs are empty when this happens.

Comment: @A.B I've updated my question, like you said Recv-Q > Send-Q. Could you have a look at the output of `ss` commands? I've checked that there were no bursts of network transfer, so I'm not sure how to interpret the results.

Comment: So you have many `CLOSE-WAIT`, probably close to the 128 threshold. CLOSE-WAIT means: "the OS told the local application that the remote peer closed the connection, but the local application didn't acknowledge this to the OS *yet*, thus the connection is kept dangling in CLOSE-WAIT". This can sometimes just be "normal" overload, or this can be a bug in the application (here nginx). From your information, this is not a network/firewall problem. You'll have to look at any logs telling what's happening that makes nginx behave like this. What's the bottleneck?

Comment: As it's nginx chances are this is caused by its backend(s). Typically some java application that has a bug and keeps a thread around instead of having it end at the end of the query, thus keeping a connection with nginx which synchronously keeps it with the remote client. Maybe there are workarounds in nginx to cope with such bugs without affecting it (pool management, timeout management etc.) but the cause would still be in the backend in such case.

Comment: @A.B I do have a couple of java applications in the backend, I'll take a closer look at them. Thanks so much for your help.